# SQL query to find ids in the same table but different timestamp events (cohorts)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to write a query that gives me the count with the following logic. The example below shows that `ACCOUNT_ID` 123 signup in `2020-02-21` so `M0` is 1 and then the same `ACCOUNT_ID` had an event in the consecutive month so `M1` is 1.

```
M0 is a the signup date
M1 is signup date + 1 month
M2 is signup date + 2 consecutive months
M3 is signup date + 3 consecutive months
```

[image]

[image]

```
    WITH M_O AS (
SELECT
    parsed_data."ACCOUNT_ID" AS "parsed_data.account_id",
    MIN(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(parsed_data."TIMESTAMP"::timestamp_ntz ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS "SIGNUP",
    COUNT(DISTINCT (parsed_data."ACCOUNT_ID") ) AS "COUNT_USERS_O"
FROM "PUBLIC"."PARSED_DATA"
     AS parsed_data

WHERE (parsed_data."ACCOUNT_ID") IS NOT NULL 
    AND (((parsed_data."EVENT") = 'Started')) 
    AND (
      ((TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(parsed_data."TIMESTAMP"::timestamp_ntz ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) >= '2020-02-21')
      AND ((parsed_data."TIMESTAMP"::timestamp_ntz ) < CURRENT_DATE())
    )
GROUP BY 1),
M_1 AS (
  SELECT
    parsed_data."ACCOUNT_ID" AS "parsed_data.account_id",
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(parsed_data."TIMESTAMP"::timestamp_ntz ), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "parsed_data.timestamp_date",
    COUNT(DISTINCT (parsed_data."ACCOUNT_ID") ) AS "COUNT_USERS_1"
  FROM "PUBLIC"."PARSED_DATA" 
    AS parsed_data INNER JOIN M_O ON parsed_data.account_id = M_O."parsed_data.account_id"
  WHERE
    (parsed_data."ACCOUNT_ID") IS NOT NULL 
    AND (((parsed_data."EVENT") = 'Started'))
    AND (
      (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(parsed_data."TIMESTAMP"::timestamp_ntz ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) >= DATEADD('MONTH', 1, SIGNUP)
      AND ((parsed_data."TIMESTAMP"::timestamp_ntz ) < CURRENT_DATE())
    )
GROUP BY 1,2
)
```

Comment: You're going to have to give some sample data.

Comment: I really suggest learning what RDBMS you are *really* using. Don't tag 3 completely different RDBMS, tag the RDBMS you are *really* using and **only** that RDBMS. This is certainly *not* SQL Server.

Comment: and you're going to need to give the table definition(s) and some idea of what the data means

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to create cohorts? As in "establish the creation date for each id, and then look how they changed their behavior every month thereafter".

This code should work:

```sql
with events as (
    select 1 id, '2020-01-01'::date e_date
    union all select 1, '2020-02-03'
    union all select 2, '2020-03-01'
    union all select 2, '2020-05-08'
    union all select 3, '2020-08-01'
    union all select 3, '2020-09-02'
    union all select 3, '2020-09-22'
    union all select 3, '2020-09-30'
    union all select 3, '2020-10-10'
),
first_per_id as (
    select id, min(e_date) first_date
    from events
    group by id
)

select a.id
    , count_if(e_date>=dateadd(month, 0, first_date) and e_date<dateadd(month, 1, first_date)) m0
    , count_if(e_date>=dateadd(month, 1, first_date) and e_date<dateadd(month, 2, first_date)) m1
    , count_if(e_date>=dateadd(month, 2, first_date) and e_date<dateadd(month, 3, first_date)) m2
from events a
join first_per_id b
where a.id=b.id
group by 1
```

[image]